# how do I get the message after submit to appear inside the pop up instead of on a different page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a contact form that I'm using Jquery .load to import a php file into any of the pages the nav will be on. Example below.

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/index.html

I'm aware that the action form needs to be changed so it is connected to the right place. But how would I do that if it is on different pages and imported into a page. Because at the moment it is set to contact.php but after it is submitted it goes to that page and doesn't import the message into the pop up. So really I need it to be the file name depending on what page it is on.

So I suppose the question is how do I get the message after submit to appear inside the pop up instead of on a different page?

Code:

```
        <?php
        $your_email = "maxlynn@madaxedesign.co.uk";
        $subject = "Email From Madaxe";
        $empty_fields_message = "<p>Please go back and complete all the fields in the form.</p>";
        $thankyou_message = "<p>Thank you. Your message has been sent. We Will reply as soon as possible.</p>";

        $name = stripslashes($_POST['txtName']);
        $email = stripslashes($_POST['txtEmail']);
        $message = stripslashes($_POST['txtMessage']);

        if (!isset($_POST['txtName'])) {

        ?>
        <form method="post" action="contact.php">
            <div id="NameEmail"> 
                <div>
                    <label for="txtName">Name*</label> 
                    <input type="text" title="Enter your name" name="txtName" />
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <label for="txtEmail">Email*</label> 
                    <input  type="text" title="Enter your email address" name="txtEmail" />
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div id="MessageSubmit">
                <div> 
                    <textarea maxlength="1200" title="Enter your message" name="txtMessage"></textarea> 
                    <label for="txtMessage">Message</label>
                </div>
                <div> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </form> 
        <?php

        }

        elseif (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)) {

        echo $empty_fields_message;

        }

        else {

            $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            $this_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if ($referer != $this_url) {
    echo "You do not have permission to use this script from another URL, nice hacking     attempt ;p.";
    exit;
            }

        mail($your_email, $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email>");

        echo $thankyou_message;

            }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax, send the email without refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is only possible in javascript, this is a language that gets executed by the browser. Javascript self is a nasty language but there are many extensions/plugins to make this very easy like jQuery. i suggest you to learn this language, you will find a new world opening in web development ;-). eg: http://learn.jquery.com/

give your form an id:
`<form method="post" id="test-form" action="contact.php">`
 so you can reference to it with jquery

now you can catch the form submit action with jQuery:

```
$('#test-form').submit(function() {
//send your data to your server and get the html data
  $.post('contact.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data){
 //here you can add the (html)data returned by the action to your page.
   $('body').append(data); //append data to body of html page
 })
 return false; //stop form from going to the next page
});
```

this code is based on a javascript plugin:  jQuery, if you want to do anything dynamic on your page without reloading the page, you need to use javascript.

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't fixed my problem, I don't fully understand how it works either which might be why? Thanks

Comment: to do what you want you need to learn javascript or anny plugin on javascript like jQuery or Dart. luckely for you this ain't an hard language to learn, i suggest you learn jQuery and you will find a new world in web development ;)